# how to create a boundry around a grid

Tags: c++

the program is supposed to output a grid of 12x24 with the all the outside line outputting 0 and the inside ones outputting 1

this is what i tried in order to get the first column and row to output 0:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define N 24
// print:
//
// Prints the simulation matrix M as spaces, *'s, and T's.
//
void print(int M[][N], int ROWS, int COLS)
{
// YOU MUST IMPLEMENT THIS:
}
//
// fill:
//
// Fills the simulation matrix such that the boundary rows
// and columns are empty, the internal area is all trees,
// and one tree is burning at index position (row, col).
//
void fill(int M[][N], int ROWS, int COLS, int row, int col)
{
// YOU MUST IMPLEMENT THIS:

//
// main:
}//
int main()
{
int M[N/2][N];
int ROWS, COLS;
int r, c;
ROWS = sizeof(M) / sizeof(M[0]);
COLS = sizeof(M[0]) / sizeof(M[0][0]);
fill(M, ROWS, COLS, 1, 1);
for(r=0; r< ROWS; r++)
{
for(c=0; c< COLS; c++)
{
    if(ROWS>1)
    {
    M[ROWS][COLS]=1;
    cout<< M[ROWS][COLS];
    }
    else
    {

    M[ROWS][COLS]=0;
    cout<< M[ROWS][COLS];
}
}
cout<< endl;
}

print(M, ROWS, COLS);
return 0; 
}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Your teacher wants you to output a grid. Why do you use a 2-dim array?

Answer (score 1):

To begin, ask yourself: **"How would I create a box?"** To create a box, you need **4 sides**. *However*, **the simplest box that one can make is involves two lines**, as we can take **the height of the box to be zero - or *infinitesimal***. In code, you'll need at least 2 rows to make a box.

Like so:

```
000000000000000
000000000000000
```

However, it has **no height.** In other words, **this is a zero-height bordered box.**

Thus to create a box like this:

```
000000000000000
011111111111110
000000000000000
```

What do you notice? **The first and the last rows are all zeroes. *And*, the first and last element of the middle row is a zero, everything else on that row is a 1.**

Extending further:

```
000000000000000
011111111111110
011111111111110
000000000000000
```

**We see the same pattern - so this can be extended for the nth row case.** Thus, the algorithm is:

1. First and last rows are all zeros.
2. For all other rows, the first and last columns of those rows are all 0.
3. Everything else is set to 1.

Hence, in your case:

```
for(r=0; r< ROWS; r++)
{
    for(c=0; c < COLS; c++)
    {
        if (r == 0 || r == ROWS - 1) {
            M[r][c]=0;
        }
        else if(c == 0 || c == COLS -1) {
            M[r][c]=0;
        }
        else {
            M[r][c]=1;  
        }
        cout<< M[r][c];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the assignments be to M[r][c]?

Comment: The only thing i forgot to ask is how the spot of M[1][1] becomes 2 because thats teh whole point of the program for it to start changing the values from that point

Comment: You're correct, @ArunSaha. Thank you! I copied the OP's code verbatim. Edited.

Comment: @RafalSwiatow, simple: assign M[1][1] to 2 like this: `M[1][1] = 2;`

Comment: However when i do assign it like that it still does not show up in the matrix, any ideas why that could be?

Comment: @RafalSwiatow, Did you do the assignment before or after you've assigned it to the default values in the loop? It will only work if the assignment is done _after_ the loop or even within the loop (which may be inefficient and/or wrong depending on how you do it). The safest bet is to do it after the loop.